# autolayout causing uitableviewcell to use path from reused cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have custom `UITableViewCells` and each cell has a `UIView` with a unique `UIBezierPath`.  Since implementing auto layout, I see that the reused cells render the path of the current cell and the path of the cell they are reusing.  So for instance, row 7 is at the top with its unique path - if I scroll down to row 2, the view in row 2 will display its own path and row 7 in the same view.  This is also true for row 6 and row 1.  If I remove all the constraints from the view in the xib file, the problem goes away.  Any idea why this is happening?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* identifier = @"audioTableCell";

    OSAudioTableCell *cell = [self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[OSAudioTableCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: identifier];
    }
    else
    {

        [cell.waveView.blueWave removeFromSuperlayer];
        [cell.waveView.redWave removeFromSuperlayer];
        cell.waveView.blueWave = nil;
        cell.waveView.redWave = nil;
        cell.waveView.path = nil;
        cell.trackLabel.text = nil;
    }

        Recording * recording = [self.fetchCon objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSData * pathData = recording.waveData;
        cell.waveView.path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:pathData];
        [cell setImageSize:cell.waveView.bounds.size];

        cell.tag = indexPath.row;

        UIView * cellBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        cellBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.multipleSelectionBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
}

-(void) prepareForReuse
{

    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.waveView.progress= 0;

}
```

Comment: Is your prepareForReuse method in your view controller or in OSAudioTableCell.m? Should be in the cell but from your code snippet it appears to be in your view controller.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying - its in OSAudioTableCell.m